# How to understand this statement about limit of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $U=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : x>a\}$, for some positive real number $a$, and let $f$ be a real-valued function on $U$. Define

$$\lim_{x\to + \infty} f(x) = \lim_{y \to 0} g(y),$$

where $g:(0, \frac{1}{a}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $g(y) = f(1/y)$, if this latter limit exists. Prove that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)$ exists if and only if, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a number $N$ such that if $x,y>N$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

Does "this latter limit exists" mean $\lim_{y \to 0} g(y)$ exists?

Comment: I guess there is a typo in the middle, it should be $g$ in the limit taken.

Comment: @user284331 Right. Thank you

Comment: The second sentence looks completely scrambled. You are not defining any limit, you are defining the function $g$. But I don't see any typo and the "latter limit" is both simultaneously, as they are equal. By the way, the limit must be $y\to0^+$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I just copied what are on the book. Page 91, introduction to analysis by Maxwell Rosenlicht, Dover Publications, inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}g(y):=L$ exists, then set $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=L$. Assume the existence of the limit of $g$, then given $\epsilon>0$, we have some $\delta>0$ such that for all $y\in(0,\delta)$, then $|g(y)-L|<\epsilon/2$. Then for all $x,y>\delta^{-1}$, we have $x^{-1},y^{-1}\in(0,\delta)$ so $|f(x)-f(y)|=|g(x^{-1})-g(y^{-1})|\leq|g(x^{-1})-L|+|g(y^{-1})-L|<\epsilon$.

Now the other direction.

It means that, if the following condition (P) is fulfilled, then prove that $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}g(y)$ exists.

(P) Given any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $N>0$ such that for every $x,y>N$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Now assume the validity of condition (P). Fix a sequence $(a_{n})$ with $a_{n}\rightarrow 0$, $a_{n}>0$. Now $n,m>N$ eventually for both $n,m$, in particular, $|g(n^{-1})-g(m^{-1})|<\epsilon$ eventually for both $n,m$. So $(g(n^{-1}))_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, it converges to $L$. By the observation that $|g(a_{n})-g(n^{-1})|<\epsilon$ eventually for $n$, it is not hard to see that $g(a_{n})$ converges to $L$. By the sequential characterisation of limit, we have $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}g(y)=L$.